# How to use Jasmine tool for SharePoint client side Unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I want to automate SharePoint unit testing using [Jasmine](http://evanhahn.com/how-do-i-jasmine/) tool.

But I don't know how to use that in SharePoint.
Can you please help us with any article or example.

Also, you can suggest tool for SharePoint client-side unit testing tool